# Увеличить размер диска CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

Забивается место на /dev/mapper/vg_centos65-lv_root (sda2). Виртуалка.

**Подскажите, как можно увеличить размер этого диска?**

[image: Скриншот размера диска]

Answer (score 0):

Добавь на виртуалку новый диск. Появится /dev/sdc.
Создай на нем раздел /dev/sdc1

```
cat << EOF | fdisk /dev/sdc
o
n
p
1


w
EOF
```

Инициализация lvm

```
pvcreate /dev/sdc1
vgextend vg_centos65 /dev/sdc1
```

Добавить место к разделу

```
lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/mapper/vg_centos65-lv_root
```

И растянуть файловую систему на это место

```
resize2fs /dev/mapper/vg_centos65-lv_root
```